# unable to translate '...' to a wide string

Tags: r, encoding

It looks to me like R introduced a new error in version 4.3.0, which breaks a lot of my web-scrapers. I only found one mention of the change, but don't really understand the [blog post](https://blog.r-project.org/2022/06/27/why-to-avoid-%5Cx-in-regular-expressions/).

In essence, this code fails on newer versions of R, but older versions do some internal conversion that seems to work:

```r
text <- "\xa0 x"
gsub("x", "u", text)
#> Warning in gsub("x", "u", text): unable to translate '<a0> x' to a wide string
#> Error in gsub("x", "u", text): input string 1 is invalid
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is there any way to remove these special characters before doing string operations? Note that I do not know which characters specifically fail, since the real strings I'm working with are too long to check.

Comment: What would be your expected output here? `<a0> u`? or `\ua0 u`?

Comment: What OS are you using? What encoding are you expecting `text` to have? Is that supposed to be a valid character string or just arbitrary bytes?

Comment: @Maël, I don't really care, I just want to be able to replace x with u. @MrFlick I'm on Linux (6.4.3-arch1-1). It should be utf8 since I create the string in R (or read it from a website with curl). I was able to parse the real strings before using ´xml2::read_html´ which also uses `grepl` under the hood and fails now.

Comment: As a "hint," or an "example,"  in R 4.2.2,  `gsub('x','u',text)`  returns `"<" "a" "0" ">" " " "x"`  . It's a matter of how `R` parses text strings before feeding them to calls.  As you found, the parser is more "picky" in 4.3x

Comment: Another thought:  if you only want to **exclude** items containing `\x`  you can write a regex something like  `[^\]x`   (probably wrong syntax)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an encoding issue, `text` is not interpreted as a valid string because it contains non-ASCII characters.

Conversion to UTF-8:

```
text_utf8 <- iconv(text, from = "ISO-8859-1", to = "UTF-8")
gsub("x","u", text_utf8)
```

will produce: `'  u'`.

[R 4.3.0 changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.pdf) says: "Regular expression functions now check more thoroughly whether their inputs are valid strings (in their encoding, e.g. in UTF-8)."

You could also treat input as sequence of bytes (this will also be preserved in the output).

```
gsub("x", "u", text, useBytes = TRUE)
```

gives `'\xa0 u'`